# Is integrating facebook allowed for desktop app?

Tags: facebook

I'm currently using facebook with my desktop app. It's working fine now.
But facebook keep requesting me to submit the app. And I cannot find an option to submit native desktop application. The only options I saw are(iOS, Android, Web... ). There is no option for native desktop app. Anyone can help?

Comment: What exactly facebook is asking to do?

Comment: I register a facebook app on developer portal and facebook keep showing a warning and ask you to fill in information and submit app detail. in app detail. You need to specify the app platform which I cannot find native windows application

Answer (score 0):

The App Detail is needed to submit in order to list your App in the Facebook App Center. It automatically fetches the details from the Settings and allow you to list the platform you want to show in the App Center.

For a web application, you can select **ON** the **Website** option in the list, here's the screenshot-

[image]

Comment: I'm using a native desktop application to integrate facebook api. In this case. There is no such option on this page.